# Movie Ticket System (DB)

Tags: sql, database, model-view-controller

I'm making a online movie reservation system on MVC and I am stuck at the database part on how the tables would link to each other. Does it seem alright?
[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvI1L.png)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Member] 
(
    [memberID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [memFirstName]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [memLastName]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [memEmailAddress] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [memPassword]     VARCHAR (15) NULL,
    [memTelephone]    CHAR (10)    NULL,
    [memAddress]      VARCHAR (70) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([memberID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Movie]
(
    [movieID]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [movieName]     VARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [movieCategory] CHAR (10)     NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([movieID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reservation] 
(
    [resID]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [memberID] INT NOT NULL,
    [showID]   INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([resID] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([memberID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Member] ([memberID]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([showID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Show] ([showID])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Show] 
(
    [showID]       INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [showDateTime] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [movieID]      INT      NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Show] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([showID] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([showID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Movie] ([movieID])    
);
```

Comment: The tables are connected with foreign key relations. If these relations are alright is entirely up to you, depending on your business requirements. What is the help you actually need?

Comment: Structure looks OK, rethink password saving logic (at least use hash, not plain text).